# How to insert values from a select query

Tags: postgresql

how do I insert the std_id value and sub_id value in the student_subject table

```
insert into student_subjects(student_id,subject_id)
            values(std_id,(select id from subjects 
                           where guid in 
                           (select * from 
                           unnest(string_to_array(subjects_colls,',')::uuid[])))::int);
```

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Comment: The error message can't be clearer. Your subquery returns more than one row. You have to modify the subquery to return only one row for your condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the `values` clause and use the SELECT directly as the source for the INSERT statement:

You also don't need to unnest your array, using `= any()` will be a bit more efficient (although I would recommend you do not pass comma separated strings, but an array of `uuid` directly)

```
insert into student_subjects(student_id,subject_id)            
select std_id, s.id 
from subjects s
where guid = any(string_to_array(subjects_colls,',')::uuid[])
```

I assume this is part of a procedure or function and `std_id` and `subjects_colls` are parameters passed to it.